# How canI dynamically add items in a list view and swap them accordingly

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create a list view, in which items can be added dynamically, the dynamic part is working fine, as it can be done using simple cursor adapter and inflating a layout with the list item, each time an item is created. But now the problem I am having is that, I want to swap these items as well, swapping as in replacing item positions. All the examples I have seen use a string array, that is a predefined list.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an Arrayadapter as your Listadapter. You can now use [insert(object, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29) to add an item to a specific position in the lists dataset. With [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) items can be removed from the lists dataset. Since the Arrayadapter will monitor changes to the dataset itself the list should update once you are done modifying the Adapter.

If you need to use a CursorAdapter this may get harder. You would need to change the underlying database and then requery the Cursor that is used in your list.

Comment: Actually I am storing my list items in a database, so I have to use cursor adapter, how can I achieve the same effect with that?